# Почему вызывается перегруженный метод?

Tags: c#, c#-faq

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     object s = A(null);
}

static object A(object s) { return s; }

static object A(string s) { return s; }
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем:

1. Почему, вызывается метод с string'овым входным параметром?
2. Почему, не вызывается метод с входным параметром object?

Где можно по этому поводу найти информацию?

Comment: [csharpindepth:Overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx), [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Напишите так  `object s = A((object)null);` и вызовется тот, что вам нужен.

Answer (score 13):

Во-первых, компилятор смотрит, какие метод вообще могут быть вызваны. Предположим, у вас три перегрузки:

```
static object A(object s) { return s; }

static object A(string s) { return s; }

static object A(int s) { return s; }
```

При вызове `A(null)` компилятор будет рассматривать только первые две перегрузки, потому что `null` не является валидным значением для типа `int`. А при вызове `A(42)` компилятор будет рассматривать только первую и третью перегрузки, потому что `42` не является валидным значением для типа `string`.

Во-вторых, из подходящих методов компилятор выберет тот метод, которые имеет *наиболее конкретный тип*. В данном случае это `string`. Таким же принципом "ближе -- лучше" компилятор руководствуется, например, и при выборе методов между текущим и родительским классом.

Подробную информацию можно найти в спецификации. Также есть краткие статьи на тему перегрузок от [Джона Скита](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx) и [Эрика Липперта](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/).